# How do I access a variable in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to build an extension, and its purpose requires me to scrape the text of the current tab and store it in a variable. Now, I'm trying to check if that worked the way it should, by console-logging the value of the variable. But it's not working in the extensions DevTools, AND in the website's DevTools.

Here is the code snippet from the frontend script (controlling the UI as the process goes on).

```js
var scrapedText = null; 

chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: 'startCapture' }, response => {
    scrapedText = response && response.scrapedText ? response.scrapedText : null;

    if (scrapedText) {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'convertToAudio', text: scrapedText });
      startButton.disabled = false;
      statusText.textContent = 'Scraping complete';
    } else {
      statusText.textContent = 'No text found on the page';
    }
  });
});
```

I'm trying to log the value of `scrapedText` in the DevTools. It's not working. Specifically, it's saying that `scrapedText` is undefined. I've tried everything, I've even been to ChatGPT, but I got nothing. For context, I'm new to extensions development.

Here's the value of the `contentScript.js` file, which is the content script.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.action === 'startCapture') {
    const textContent = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*')).map(element => element.textContent).join(' ');
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'scrapedText', content: textContent }, response => {
      sendResponse({ scrapedText: textContent });
    });
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: In your content script you've used `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(..)` You should just directly call `sendResponse({ scrapedText: textContent });`.

Comment: "I've even been to chatgpt, but I got nothing." - I'm glad to hear that, because ChatGPT's answers are usually complete nonsense.

Comment: "I've tried everything" - Have you tried reading the documentation? I understand that this takes time, but it's the best way to learn extension development.